# Is it suitable to use $httpBackend in production to abstract data service requests?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have a data service in my application that is responsible for retrieving information for my controllers. This information might come from local storage, window or an ajax request. The problem I am facing is the `$q` promise responses don't look like `$http` responses.

```
    this.getContactDetails = function(data) {
        // The first time this method is called, we expect contact details to be preloaded on the page.
        // We want to read and return that object then remove it from the page so subsequent requests are to the server.
        if(typeof $window.preloadData.contact !== 'undefined') {
            var contactDetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($window.preloadData.contact));
            delete $window.preloadData.contact;
            // Since the method call should always have the same return type, we manually create a deferred object and set the resolution using the $q service.
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(contactDetails);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        var request = requests.contactDetails.get;
        return $http(request);
    };
```

The `$q` service does a nice job here but it resolves as the object it was given. I wouldn't really expect it to wrap the response. I know `$httpBackend` *could* accomplish this.

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(request).respond(contactDetails);
```

But the service is used in the MockE2E library and I doubt this was its intended use. I am not sure how to call this off afterwards or what would happen if I used it twice on the same request but I can figure out these questions. My other concern is that there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the same config object to $httpBackend as I do to $http. $httpBackend only accepts a method, url, body and headers, while $http config allows me to specify parameters.

Currently my work-around is simply to create and $http-like wrapper myself.

```
var contactDetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
    data: $window.preloadData.contact
}));
```

But I don't find this very elegant. Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: As a minor thing, you can use [`angular.copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) instead of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.

Comment: Actually I just got schooled on javascript pass-by-reference (again) and learned that I don't even need to copy it since I am deleting the $window reference only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your storage layer as a [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory) and add it to [$httpProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#caching) during the configuration phase.

From the docs:

> When the cache is enabled, $http stores the response from the server in the specified cache. The next time the same request is made, the response is served from the cache without sending a request to the server.

Hence, if you provide your own implementation of a *cache* with the following methods:

> - {object} info() — Returns id, size, and options of cache.
> - `{{*}}` put({string} key, `{*}` value) — Puts a new key-value pair into the cache and returns it.
> - `{{*}}` get({string} key) — Returns cached value for key or undefined for cache miss.
> - {void} remove({string} key) — Removes a key-value pair from the cache.
> - {void} removeAll() — Removes all cached values.
> - {void} destroy() — Removes references to this cache from $cacheFactory.

You can return values read from `localStorage`, session cookies, etc. and they will be treated as there were `data` sent from the server, just without the AJAX request.

Comment: How does that serve to abstract requests? I want to make the response look the same in the returned promise whether it is coming from a $cacheFactory, window, localStorage or an $Http request.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how I would be able to implement a cacheFactory that serves as an anti-cache. My use case is actually to serve and consume local sources first then make remote requests.

Comment: @ogc-nick Override the `get` method: _`{{*}}` get({string} key) — Returns cached value for key or undefined for cache miss._ to return the values you want if you have them on the client. Else return `undefined` and let the `$http` request go through.

Comment: I see. So it looks like from the docs I can pass in a $cache object to use request-specific caching logic. Perfect.